# how to adjust my code to send data in json format in angular

Tags: node.js, json, angular, express

I hope you can help me, I need to send some parameters in json format like this:

```
{
"InformationA": {
"str_id": 1,
"str_description": "message",
"str_email": "abcd@abcd.com.co"
},
"AddConfiguration": [
{
"int_code": 1,
"str_valor": "32201"
},
{
"int_code": 104,
"str_valor": "https://www.google.com.co/"
},
{
"int_code": 108,
"str_valor": "1"
}
]
}
```

I am trying to send the json through the angular service in this way but I don't know if it is correct?:

```
sendData(InformationA,AddConfiguration){
const params = 'InformationA=' +JSON.stringify(InformationA)+'AddConfiguration=' + 
JSON.stringify(AddConfiguration);
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.route}/send-data`, params , { headers: this.headers });
}
```

also create a function in the nodejs backend to see how it would arrive:

```
@Post('send-data')
async receibeData(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
try {
const data = req.body;
res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(data)
} catch (err) {
throw err;
}
}
```

and by console it is printed in this way:

```
{,…}
InformationA:" 
[{"str_id":"1","str_description":"message","str_email":"abcd@abcd.com.co"}]Addconfiguration= 
[{"int_code":1,"str_valor":"32201 "},{"int_code":104,"str_valor":"https://www.google.com.co 
"},{"int_code":108,"str_valor":"1 "}]"
```

I am really very new to this and I would like to know how I adapt my data so that it can be sent as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to build the JSON object corresponding to your requirement. You should not use JSON.stringify for this purpose. I hope this will help you out.

```
sendData(InformationA,AddConfiguration) {
const params = {
        InformationA: InformationA,
        AddConfiguration: AddConfiguration
};
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.route}/send-data`, params , { headers: this.headers });
}
```

Comment: hi, when making that change by console it is printed like this: {{"InformationA":: {,…}}
{"InformationA":: {,…}
{"str_id":"1","str_description":"message","str_email":"abcd@abcd.com"}: {,…}{"int_code":50,"str_valor":"2701 "},{"int_code":104,"str_valor":"https://www.google.com.co"},{"int_code":108,"str_valor":"1 "}: ""

Comment: Sorry.I made a mistake when build the JSON object.Please try this way             
 ***const params = {
        'InformationA': InformationA,
        'AddConfiguration': AddConfiguration
};***                                                                     Make your property as string.